# Взаимодействие с внешним приложением, winapi

Tags: c#, winapi, авторизация

Для изучения используется приложение Steam.

Имеется окно входа с полями "Логин" и "Пароль". Как передать им значения если:

1) Хендл имеет только главное окно (дочерних окон нет)
2) Окно должно быть скрыто от пользователя (без разницы - на заднем плане или вообще только в виде процесса)
3) Название класса главного окна при каждом запуске меняется (не проблема, но вдруг)

Открываю следующим образом:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "D:/Games/Steam/Steam.exe";
process.Start();
```

Изначально планировал сделать ввод через SendMessage напрямую, но нужно знать адрес цели (пункт 1). Потом хотел передавать нажатия клавиш окну, но для этого оно должно быть активным (пункт 2). Пока копаю в сторону steam-web-api, но если попадутся другие приложения с той же проблемой?

Не хочется собирать грабли, может кто сталкивался с подобными задачами. Чтоб не ругались, собственно вопрос: как взаимодействовать с окном учитывая все выше перечисленные "если"?

Comment: "Пока копаю в сторону steam-web-api, но если попадутся другие приложения с той же проблемой?" То у них либо тоже есть API, либо проблема решается перехватом пакетов хотя бы с помощью Fiddler, Wireshark, и их имитацией, а по-хорошему еще нужно владеть отладкой как минимум JS. А ваше "изучение" - это детсад, поэтому не стоит даже обсуждать. P.S. А вот окна в большинстве приложений как раз не рассчитаны на управление через WinAPI. Хотя бы через Accessibility, если на то пошло. Большинство приложений, о котором я пишу - это Chrome, Chrome, Chrome, Chrome, Chrome, Chrome и Chrome - 7 шт целых.

Comment: Посмотрите [SteamKit](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit).

Comment: @Rou1997 Steam-Web-Api на то и Web, что работает только с сайтами, ну по крайней мере других его использований я не нашел, да и дает он только информацию сообщества, а не то что нужно. Вот с перехватом пакетов интересная мыслью. И можно поподробнее об отладке внешнего windows-приложения, даже если оно использует js?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Если это не браузер, а именно внешнее приложение, то следует поискать его скрипты, откуда-то же оно берет js - либо с сервера (можно перехватить и в том же сниффере настроить изменение на лету), либо из папки в Program Files, скорее часть оттуда, часть отсюда. В этот JS можно вставить хуки, чтобы достать интересующую инфу и как-то залогировать. Ну можно и круче - IDA Pro + HexRays и все такое, но это тяжелая артиллерия и вам все равно понадобится не один месяц разобраться с этим.